# Is this Fafco valve actuator actually a Jandy?

Tags: water, valve, pool, solar-panels

My pool's solar panel valve actuator is not working any more. The temperature panel lights up but the valve seems broken. It doesn't move and I can't manually adjust the handle. I bought the house a couple of years ago after it was foreclosed on. I don't have any info on what was installed by the previous owner but the housing says "Fafco" on the top and "Jandy Valve" on the handle. I can't find any valve actuators made by "Fafco" online and nothing comes up for what appears to be the model number on the side.... Can I replace it with the Jandy 2444 valve actuator? They look exactly the same from the pictures I've seen.

This is what I've got...
[image]

And this is what I am looking to replace it with...
http://poolandspasupply.com/jandy-4424-jva-2444-aqualink-valve-actuator.html
[image]

Comment: Seems plausible. I'd **check the voltage** of the existing system - if it seems to be 24VAC as the new one is, then might as well give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't manually operate the handle, the actuator might not be at fault - the actual valve might be jammed (or the actuator might be jammed, keeping you from operating the valve by hand, I guess.)

In any case, you should probably take the actuator off and verify if the valve can be operated by hand without it in place - if not, the new one won't have much joy either.

Comment: I have never been able to move it manually even when it was working. I thought I was doing something wrong after I saw a couple of videos today where people were able to move it on VAs that looked similar but I tried it one more time when I got home and had no luck. Maybe that just wasn't an option for whatever VA I have.

Comment: I think he was indicating that you should take the VA off and attempt to move the valve by hand.  If you can't actuate the valve manually (without the VA in place), the valve may be the problem, not the actuator.

Comment: That's basically the idea, though given the pictured setup I also think you should be able to do it with the actuator in place (but powered off) or else why would there even be a manual handle mounted on top of it at all? But if the current one is jammed, taking it off would allow for isolating "actuator jammed" .vs. "valve jammed" as a root problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you loosen the screw that holds the handle to the top of the actuator, you can push down on the screw and it will (should) disengage the gear drive in the actuator. That will allow you to move the valve. If the actuator is actually bad, any actuator made for operating Jandy valves can be used... You may have a power issue as well, no power and the valve won't operate.